# Htaccess - Redirect all but one url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all urls from one domain to another but one (kind of). This is the htaccess I have to redirect all keeping the same url except of the domain (for example domain.com/something goes to domain2.com/something).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://domain2.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

What I want to know is how to redirect all except if the url is domain.com/validation/*

/validation/ is not a subfolder and it has to be the next part of the url after the domain (domain.com/something/validation can redirect, and domain.com/validation/something can't).

I tried a lot of options but none worked :(

I hope is enough information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude it in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^validation http://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```